# WebSocket connection failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to integrate Socket.io with Angular and I'm having difficulties making a connection from the client-side to the server. I've looked through other related questions but my issue is happening locally, so there's no web server in the middle.

This is what my server code looks like:

```javascript
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('greet', { hello: 'Hey, Mr.Client!' });

  socket.on('respond', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('Socket disconnected');
  });
});
```

I'm loading the client side JavaScript files using Grunt in the following order:

```
dist: {
    src: [
        public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js,
        ...
        public/bower_components/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min.js,
        public/bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.min.js,
        ...
    ]
}
```

Then in my controller:

```javascript
function MyController($scope) {

    let socket = io.connect(window.location.href);
    socket.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('greet', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      socket.emit('respond', { message: 'Hello to you too, Mr.Server!' });
    });

    ...
}
```

Before actually using the `btford/angular-socket-io` library, I want to make sure that I can get a connection correctly, but I get the following error in the console:

[image: socket io connection error message]

The interesting thing is that if I restart the Node.js server process, it does manage to send the message but using polling instead of websockets.

[image: after restart]

[image: polling message]

I tried all sorts of different options in the socket.connect call, but nothing worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

### UPDATE (30/12/2016):

I just realized that websockets is working partially. I see a 101 Switching Protocols request in the Chrome developer console. However the only frames I see there are the engine.io protocol packets (ping, pong). However my application socket messages still fall back to polling for some reason...

[image: engine.io packets]

Comment: do you use nginx as proxy server?

Comment: Hey digit, nope, no web servers as of yet. I read about having to set the Upgrade header for it to work,  but I'm just developing locally at the moment.

Comment: I have this problem with pusher and laravel. I dont know why but i get this error :((

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Problem solved! I just figured out how to solve the issue, but I would still like to know if this is normal behavior or not.

It seems that even though the Websocket connection establishes correctly (indicated by the 101 Switching Protocols request), it still defaults to long-polling. The fix was as simple as adding this option to the Socket.io connection function:

```
{transports: ['websocket']}
```

So the code finally looks like this:

```
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('connected socket!');

  socket.on('greet', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('respond', { hello: 'Hey, Mr.Client!' });
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('Socket disconnected');
  });
});
```

and on the client:

```
var socket = io('ws://localhost:3000', {transports: ['websocket']});
socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('connected!');
  socket.emit('greet', { message: 'Hello Mr.Server!' });
});

socket.on('respond', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

And the messages now appear as frames:

[working websockets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFGeI.png)

This [Github issue](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/991) pointed me in the right direction. Thanks to everyone who helped out!

Comment: How did you get chrome to show the frames like that?  When I click on a sockIO request it does not show a tab for Frames

Comment: When the browser initiates the connection it sends an upgrade request to which the server responds with a 101 Switching protocols. You have to make sure that you look for this request in the Network tab, as it will be the one that shows the frames sent between the two entities.

Comment: Yes I've navigated there.  There are several cases where the "frames" tab is not there in the Network tab.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me, had same issue as OP

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfect. I'd switched from Heroku to glitch because of some port binding issue on Heroku, then I got this error on glitch.

Comment: Note that adding this option effectively removes long-polling fallback, which is one of the reasons `socket.io` is so robust in the first place. See [https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/).

Answer (score 64):

### This worked for me with Nginx, Node server and Angular 4

Edit your nginx web server config file as:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 52.xx.xxx.xx;

location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:4200";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Comment: even though the OP is asking about a local issue where there is no nginx reverse proxy involved this answer is the correct nginx setting when its in play

Comment: Adding the upgrade headers for my configuration was what I needed. `proxy_http_version 1.1;` caused the Nginx service to fail to start.

Comment: For those who would like more info regarding nginx header management:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching

Comment: And for those wanting to know why the upgrade header?
https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Comment: the last two lines for upgrade were missing from mine.

Comment: Or you can just follow a wiki  to set things up:
https://github.com/foundry-vtt-community/wiki/wiki/Ubuntu-VM

Comment: This was my problem, server was working smoothly on local network, but when I made it a public server with nginx random connection fails happened. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 37):

The currently [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381444/#answer-41396396) is misleading.

According to the [official documentation](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/), adding the `transports: [ 'websocket' ]` option effectively removes the ability to fallback to long-polling when the websocket connection cannot be established. This option is what makes `socket.io` so robust in the first place because it can adapt to many scenarios.

In that particular case where one wishes to solely rely on websockets, directly using the [`WebSocket API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) is recommended.

For other cases (supposedly most users), this is most likely a reverse proxy/server configuration problem.

The official documentation suggests the following depending on your environment:

### NginX configuration

```
http {
  server {
    listen 3000;
    server_name io.yourhost.com;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_pass http://nodes;

      # enable WebSockets
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
  }

  upstream nodes {
    # enable sticky session based on IP
    ip_hash;

    server app01:3000;
    server app02:3000;
    server app03:3000;
  }
}
```

### Apache HTTPD configuration

```
Header add Set-Cookie "SERVERID=sticky.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED

<Proxy "balancer://nodes_polling">
    BalancerMember "http://app01:3000" route=app01
    BalancerMember "http://app02:3000" route=app02
    BalancerMember "http://app03:3000" route=app03
    ProxySet stickysession=SERVERID
</Proxy>

<Proxy "balancer://nodes_ws">
    BalancerMember "ws://app01:3000" route=app01
    BalancerMember "ws://app02:3000" route=app02
    BalancerMember "ws://app03:3000" route=app03
    ProxySet stickysession=SERVERID
</Proxy>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://nodes_ws/$1 [P,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://nodes_polling/$1 [P,L]

ProxyTimeout 3
```

### HAProxy configuration

```
listen chat
  bind *:80
  default_backend nodes

backend nodes
  option httpchk HEAD /health
  http-check expect status 200
  cookie io prefix indirect nocache # using the `io` cookie set upon handshake
  server app01 app01:3000 check cookie app01
  server app02 app02:3000 check cookie app02
  server app03 app03:3000 check cookie app03
```

Also worth reading [this](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/websockets-load-balancing-with-haproxy/) on upgrading connections in HAProxy.

For more details please refer to the official documentation link above.

EDIT:

### Varnish (source [here](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/users-guide/vcl-example-websockets.html))

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.upgrade ~ "(?i)websocket") {
        return (pipe);
    }
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    if (req.http.upgrade) {
        set bereq.http.upgrade = req.http.upgrade;
        set bereq.http.connection = req.http.connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: My websocket connection upgrade fails. Don't know why. I have this config for nginx 

`location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwared-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        client_max_body_size 100M;
    }`

Comment: Sorry for the late response @invider @Norbert. Have you fixed your problem? I see there's a typo in `proxy_set_header X-Forwared-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` - it should be `X-Forwarded-For`. Also have you double-checked whether your proxy_pass target is reachable (and specifically via port 3000)?

Comment: Don't remember actually

Answer (score 14):

I solved this by changing transports from 'websocket' to 'polling'

```
   var socket = io.connect('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000', {
      transports: ['polling']
   });
```

Comment: This is more of a band-aid than a real fix. Socket.io uses a poll to connect initially then "upgrades" to more reliable transports (i.e. websockets). This answer forces socketio to only use polling (and not more efficient transports) which will fix the error but isn't a long-term solution if you prefer to avoid endless polling in larger apps. I believe socketio knows to fail to polling if the upgrade fails as well, so you're more or less saving yourself the console error.

Answer (score 9):

Judging from the messages you send via Socket.IO `socket.emit('greet', { hello: 'Hey, Mr.Client!' });`, it seems that you are using the `hackathon-starter` boilerplate. If so, the issue might be that `express-status-monitor` module is creating its own socket.io instance, as per: https://github.com/RafalWilinski/express-status-monitor#using-module-with-socketio-in-project

You can either:

1. Remove that module
2. Pass in your socket.io instance and port as `websocket` when you create the `expressStatusMonitor` instance like below:

   ```
   const server = require('http').Server(app);
   const io = require('socket.io')(server);
   ...
   app.use(expressStatusMonitor({ websocket: io, port: app.get('port') }));
   ```

Comment: Super! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue, my app is behind nginx. Making these changes to my Nginx config removed the error.

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had faced same issues, I refined apache2 virtual host entery and got success.

Note: on server I had succesful installed and working on 9001 port without any issue. This guide line for apache2 only no relavence with nginx, this answer for apache2+etherpad lovers.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName pad.tejastank.com
  ServerAlias pad.tejastank.com
  ServerAdmin snippetbucket@gmail.com

  LoadModule  proxy_module         /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
  LoadModule  proxy_http_module    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
  LoadModule  headers_module       /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so
  LoadModule  deflate_module       /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so

  ProxyVia On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost on

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:9001/ retry=0 timeout=30
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9001/
    </Location>
    <Location /socket.io>
        # This is needed to handle the websocket transport through the proxy, since
        # etherpad does not use a specific sub-folder, such as /ws/ to handle this kind of traffic.
        # Taken from https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/issues/2318#issuecomment-63548542
        # Thanks to beaugunderson for the semantics
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
        RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:9001/socket.io/$1 [P,L]
        ProxyPass http://localhost:9001/socket.io retry=0 timeout=30
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9001/socket.io
    </Location>


  <Proxy *>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Advance tips:
Please with help of a2enmod enable all mod of apache2

Restart apache2 than will get effect. But obvious a2ensite to enable site required.

Note: currently my backend system do not have https, so I keep http, in case your backend is already enable with HTTPS then use https:// for backend. In case your backend already in HTTPS I am worries for overhead load on HTTPS, My suggestion is to backend should be in http when private server under tidy security. Decision is yours.

Comment: I changed all of your `http://` to `https://` and `ws://` to `wss://` -- works fine.  thank you so much for sharing this. 
Using localhost:### in this context is very interesting, i have never seen that before.

Comment: Yea this worked for me. Thanks.
The rewrite rules was the problem for me maybe

Comment: That worked for me - the `<Location /socket.io>` I did not wrap my settings in that... but yeah helped a lot. Thanks Dude!

Comment: Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you are using an `http` scheme, but I think you should be using a `ws` scheme, as you are using websockets. Try to use `ws://localhost:3000` in your connect function.

Comment: Hey Mattia, no luck. I tried using ws instead of http but the issue persists. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define your `origins` for client side as bellow:

```js
//server.js
const socket = require('socket.io');
const app = require('express')();
const server = app.listen('port');

const io = socket().attach(server);
io.origins("your_domain:port www.your_domain:port your_IP:port your_domain:*")

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('connected a new client');
});

//client.js
var socket = io('ws://:port');
```

Comment: extend your origins by adding other patterns like `http://your_IP:port` or `http://your_domain:port`

Comment: Nope, unfortunately that didn't seem to do the trick. Any other ideas why this could be rejecting the use of websockets with a 400 Bad Request? What boggles me is that this is all in localhost, so there shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're using port 3000 on the client-side. I'd hazard a guess that's the Angular port and not the server port? It should be connecting to the server port.

Answer (score 1):

In my similar scenario, `express-status-monitor` was installed to remove and remediate this error

The following are the steps / settings / configuration to install `express-status-monitor`:

```
npm i express-status-monitor --save
```

```js
const expressStatusMonitor = require('express-status-monitor');
app.use(expressStatusMonitor({
    websocket: io,
    port: app.get('port')
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was not got the port from `process.env.PORT` it is very important because Heroku and other services properly do a random port numbers to use.

So that is the code that work for me eventuly :

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
const serverPort = process.env.PORT ; //<----- important 

const io = require('socket.io')(http,{
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS'.split(','),
    credentials: true
  }
});

http.listen(serverPort,()=>{
  console.log(`server listening on port ${serverPort}`)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error witk socket.io on node.js but the reason was quite silly. There wasn't all socket.io's dependencies installed correctly, namely package base64id was missed

Answer (score 1):

Including `transports: ['websocket']` is not the best approach as it removes Sockt.io functionality from suiting any scenario.

In my case using Nodejs + Nginx + Vuejs/Vite(Front) I managed to solve it by configuring the reverse proxy in the site configuration in Nginx.

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html;

    // <---- start ---->
    location /socket.io/ { // <--- Set your custom path
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; // <--- Set your Port

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
    // <---- End ---->

  }
}
```

You can find references on this issue on the [Socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v4/reverse-proxy/#nginx) website or on [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/)

Answer (score 1):

If you tried every option given above then there is no problem with your code, try to stop the ad blocker of your browser. It worked for me

**My Output after disabling blocker**
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8WO0.png)

**My server**
[Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WPDv.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using flask, gunicorn and nginx as your reverse proxy, configuring adding these options under the endpoint where socket.io is being used is not enough.

This is what I mean, consider that you have an endpoint '/chat' configured as follows:

```
location /chat/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    # Enable websockets
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

After I did this, I still kept on encountering the error: `WebSocket connection to 'ws://x.x.x.x/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=LNcNgeauE7z6dYBiAAAK' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`.

To solve this, I added another endpoint in my conf i.e.,

```
location /socket.io/ { 
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;

     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; # Remember to change to your configured port

     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

After adding and configuring this endpoint, I did not get a single ws error.

Further references: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

Answer (score 0):

After using following load balancer setting my problem solved for wss but for ws problem still exists for specific one ISP.

[calssic-load-balancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kzoh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing `io.listen(server);`. I started running into this error when I started integrating passport.socketio and using passport middleware.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using httpd/apache, you can add a file something like ws.conf and add this code to it. Also, this solution can proxy something like this "http://localhost:6001/socket.io" to just this "http://localhost/socket.io"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on

    #redirect WebSocket
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:6001/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass        /socket.io http://localhost:6001/socket.io
    ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:6001/socket.io
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Apollo Server 2.

Per https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4778#issuecomment-509638071, this solved my problem:

> try 'ws://localhost:4000/graphql'

...since incoming and outgoing requests now use the same address.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was with server side

```
const app = require("express")();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);
```

listen with

```
http.listen(PORT,()=> console.log('listening'))
```

it was giving me error when i did

```
app.listen(......)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure you tick hide network box on console