# When i run angular project: I got Websocket error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

**I got below error in chrome:**

sockjs.js:1679 WebSocket connection to 'ws://admin.petnpals.com/sockjs-node/798/b4hhl1c2/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

**& in firefox:**

[WDS] Disconnected!
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://admin.petnpals.com/sockjs-node/716/21e2eaz1/websocket.

Please help if anyone know the solution.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: can you please add some code.

Comment: also which server you are using?

Comment: We are using centos server.

Comment: Which code you want?

Comment: for your project you might be using some server Apache, Ngnix or anything

Comment: Please add code part where you are getting error

Comment: This is my site url: https://www.petnpals.com/ 
You can see error in console.

Comment: I use MEAN stack project, MongoDB, ExpressJs, Angular, Nodejs Combination.

Comment: Please check this URL once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381444/websocket-connection-failed-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-respon

Comment: Also, https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942