# how to solve EADDRINUSE in GKE container?

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am new to containers and using GKE. I used to run my node server app with `npm run debug` and am trying to do this as well on GKE using the shell of my container. When I log into the shell of `myapp` container and do this I get:

```
> api_server@0.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> node src/

events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8089
```

Normally I deal with this using something like [`killall -9 node`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs) but when I do this it looks like I am kicked out of my shell and the container is restarted by kubernetes. It seems node is using the port already or something:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 8089
tcp        0      0 :::8089                 :::*                    LISTEN      23/node
```

How can I start my server from the shell?

My config files:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN apk add --update \
libc6-compat

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY templates-mjml/ templates-mjml/
COPY public/ public/
COPY src/ src/
COPY data/ data/
COPY config/ config/
COPY migrations/ migrations/
ENV NODE_ENV 'development'
ENV PORT '8089'
RUN npm install --development
```

myapp.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8089
    name: http
  selector:
    app: myapp    
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: gcr.io/myproject-224713/firstapp:v4
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8089
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB_HOST
              value: 127.0.0.1:5432
            - name: POSTGRES_DB_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysecret
                  key: username
            - name: POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysecret
                  key: password       
        - name: cloudsql-proxy
          image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
          command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
                    "-instances=myproject-224713:europe-west4:mydatabase=tcp:5432",
                    "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 2
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
              mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
---
```

myrouter.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: myapp-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - myapp-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: myapp
      weight: 100
    websocketUpgrade: true
```

EDIT:
I got following logs:[image]

EDIT 2:
After adding a [featherjs health service](https://think-engineer.com/blog/cloud-computing/exposing-a-feathers-js-http-api-in-kubernetes-using-ingress) I get following output for `describe`:

```
Name:           myapp-95df4dcd6-lptnq
Namespace:      default
Node:           gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3/10.164.0.3
Start Time:     Wed, 02 Jan 2019 22:08:33 +0100
Labels:         app=myapp
                pod-template-hash=518908782
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/limit-ranger: LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container myapp; cpu request for container cloudsql-proxy
                sidecar.istio.io/status:
                  {"version":"3c9617ff82c9962a58890e4fa987c69ca62487fda71c23f3a2aad1d7bb46c748","initContainers":["istio-init"],"containers":["istio-proxy"]...
Status:         Running
IP:             10.44.3.17
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/myapp-95df4dcd6
Init Containers:
  istio-init:
    Container ID:  docker://768b2327c6cfa57b3d25a7029e52ce6a88dec6848e91dd7edcdf9074c91ff270
    Image:         gcr.io/gke-release/istio/proxy_init:1.0.2-gke.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://gcr.io/gke-release/istio/proxy_init@sha256:e30d47d2f269347a973523d0c5d7540dbf7f87d24aca2737ebc09dbe5be53134
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      -p
      15001
      -u
      1337
      -m
      REDIRECT
      -i
      *
      -x

      -b
      8089,
      -d

    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Wed, 02 Jan 2019 22:08:34 +0100
      Finished:     Wed, 02 Jan 2019 22:08:35 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:         <none>
Containers:
  myapp:
    Container ID:   docker://5566a3e8242ec6755dc2f26872cfb024fab42d5f64aadc3db1258fcb834f8418
    Image:          gcr.io/myproject-224713/firstapp:v4
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://gcr.io/myproject-224713/firstapp@sha256:0cbd4fae0b32fa0da5a8e6eb56cb9b86767568d243d4e01b22d332d568717f41
    Port:           8089/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 02 Jan 2019 22:09:19 +0100
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Wed, 02 Jan 2019 22:08:35 +0100
      Finished:     Wed, 02 Jan 2019 22:09:19 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  1
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
    Liveness:   http-get http://:8089/health delay=15s timeout=20s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get http://:8089/health delay=5s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      POSTGRES_DB_HOST:      127.0.0.1:5432
      POSTGRES_DB_USER:      <set to the key 'username' in secret 'mysecret'>  Optional: false
      POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'password' in secret 'mysecret'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-9vtz5 (ro)
  cloudsql-proxy:
    Container ID:  docker://414799a0699abe38c9759f82a77e1a3e06123714576d6d57390eeb07611f9a63
    Image:         gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy@sha256:5c690349ad8041e8b21eaa63cb078cf13188568e0bfac3b5a914da3483079e2b
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /cloud_sql_proxy
      -instances=myproject-224713:europe-west4:osm=tcp:5432
      -credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 02 Jan 2019 22:08:36 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /secrets/cloudsql from cloudsql-instance-credentials (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-9vtz5 (ro)
  istio-proxy:
    Container ID:  docker://898bc95c6f8bde18814ef01ce499820d545d7ea2d8bf494b0308f06ab419041e
    Image:         gcr.io/gke-release/istio/proxyv2:1.0.2-gke.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://gcr.io/gke-release/istio/proxyv2@sha256:826ef4469e4f1d4cabd0dc846f9b7de6507b54f5f0d0171430fcd3fb6f5132dc
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      proxy
      sidecar
      --configPath
      /etc/istio/proxy
      --binaryPath
      /usr/local/bin/envoy
      --serviceCluster
      myapp
      --drainDuration
      45s
      --parentShutdownDuration
      1m0s
      --discoveryAddress
      istio-pilot.istio-system:15007
      --discoveryRefreshDelay
      1s
      --zipkinAddress
      zipkin.istio-system:9411
      --connectTimeout
      10s
      --statsdUdpAddress
      istio-statsd-prom-bridge.istio-system:9125
      --proxyAdminPort
      15000
      --controlPlaneAuthPolicy
      NONE
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 02 Jan 2019 22:08:36 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:  10m
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:                      myapp-95df4dcd6-lptnq (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:                 default (v1:metadata.namespace)
      INSTANCE_IP:                    (v1:status.podIP)
      ISTIO_META_POD_NAME:           myapp-95df4dcd6-lptnq (v1:metadata.name)
      ISTIO_META_INTERCEPTION_MODE:  REDIRECT
    Mounts:
      /etc/certs/ from istio-certs (ro)
      /etc/istio/proxy from istio-envoy (rw)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True 
  Ready          False 
  PodScheduled   True 
Volumes:
  cloudsql-instance-credentials:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  cloudsql-instance-credentials
    Optional:    false
  default-token-9vtz5:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-9vtz5
    Optional:    false
  istio-envoy:
    Type:    EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:  Memory
  istio-certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  istio.default
    Optional:    true
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age                From                                                        Message
  ----     ------                 ----               ----                                                        -------
  Normal   Scheduled              68s                default-scheduler                                           Successfully assigned myapp-95df4dcd6-lptnq to gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  68s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "istio-envoy"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  68s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-9vtz5"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  68s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "cloudsql-instance-credentials"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  68s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "istio-certs"
  Normal   Pulled                 67s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Container image "gcr.io/gke-release/istio/proxy_init:1.0.2-gke.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                67s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Created container
  Normal   Started                67s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Started container
  Normal   Pulled                 66s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Container image "gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                66s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Created container
  Normal   Started                66s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Started container
  Normal   Created                65s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Created container
  Normal   Started                65s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Started container
  Normal   Pulled                 65s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Container image "gcr.io/gke-release/istio/proxyv2:1.0.2-gke.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                65s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Created container
  Normal   Started                65s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Started container
  Warning  Unhealthy              31s (x4 over 61s)  kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
  Normal   Pulled                 22s (x2 over 66s)  kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Container image "gcr.io/myproject-224713/firstapp:v4" already present on machine
  Warning  Unhealthy              22s (x3 over 42s)  kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
  Normal   Killing                22s                kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-59600833-pcj3  Killing container with id docker://myapp:Container failed liveness probe.. Container will be killed and recreated.
```

Comment: What is the reason you're not starting your app in the container right away (I mean: in the dockerfile)?

Comment: Actually he probably is and thats what is causing the ADDR IN USE error?

Comment: At least not in the dockerfile he posted :)

Comment: @Fred I used to do that but took that out of my Dockerfile, since that gives me an [CrashLoopBackOff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53987459/websockets-on-gke-with-istio-gives-no-healthy-upstream-and-crashloopbackoff) which I am now trying to debug...

Comment: @musicformellons Check the logs k8s is dumping in the dashboard. I don't see a readinessprobe or livelinessprobe in your config, maybe that's the reason for the crashloop.

Comment: @Fred Yeah.., I was already suspicious about 'readiness' as I think I might need to add an dedicated [feathersjs service for this](https://think-engineer.com/blog/cloud-computing/exposing-a-feathers-js-http-api-in-kubernetes-using-ingress). I do not know much about logs... but I added the logs I found in the question which do mention 'readiness' etc. Please comment.

Comment: You will need a working health check. You can build a small server on top with hapijs or whatever you need. Make sure you test your container locally so that it has a working /health endpoint. Then add a section to the deployment part of your yaml

Comment: @Fred As I am using Feathersjs I will make a health check service with that. To me it does not seem to be the cause of the EADDRINUSE error though?! Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

This is just how Kubernetes works, as long as your pod has processes running it will remain 'up'. The moment you kill one if its processes Kubernetes will restart the pod because it crashed or something went wrong.

If you really want to debug with `npm run debug` consider either:

1. Create a container with the [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) (at the end) or [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) value in your Dockerfile that is `npm run debug`. Then run it using a Deployment definition in Kubernetes.
2. Override the command in the `myapp` container in your deployment definition with something like:

   ```
   spec:
     containers:
       - name: myapp
         image: gcr.io/myproject-224713/firstapp:v4
         ports:
           - containerPort: 8089
         command: ["npm", "run", "debug" ]
         env:
           - name: POSTGRES_DB_HOST
             value: 127.0.0.1:5432
           - name: POSTGRES_DB_USER
             valueFrom:
               secretKeyRef:
                 name: mysecret
                 key: username
           - name: POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD
             valueFrom:
               secretKeyRef:
                 name: mysecret
                 key: password
   ```

Comment: Ok. I extended my CMD with ```ENV NODE_ENV 'development'
ENV PORT '8089'
RUN npm install --development

EXPOSE 8089
CMD [ "npm", "run", "debug" ]``` but now get readiness and liveness probe failures, see EDIT 2 of my question.

Comment: The liveness and readiness probes point to `http://:8089/health` and you are getting a 404 (not found). Is that the right URL for health?

Comment: AFAIK yes. The path of the health service is indeed ```/health``` and port is ```8089```. The host is missing in the url, which bothered me, but I read in [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#configure-probes) that it sets the IP of the pod as default host, so should be ok I think.

Comment: your delays for liveness and readiness probes look odd.  Generally, you want a shorter delay on the liveness probe... and many you just want to hit the `/` path. then your readiness probe can hit `/health`

Comment: Ah! I solved the health service issue (forgot to give permissions to unauthenticated users) and that works now. I am still 'stuck' though as myapp container still crashes when I use websockets, which was what I wanted to debug in the first place...

Comment: That is great! Good to hear.