# Permissions on GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

After creation of a standard GKE cluster in the Google Cloud Platform Console I find when I click on the cluster and look at the clusters' setting s a 'Permissions' setting, which looks like this:
[image]

what I don't understand is that I have allowed API access on a lot of these service I believe, so why does only 'Cloud Platform' show 'enabled'? Is this what is enabled at creation of the cluster maybe?!

When selecting 'edit' you can not 'enable' these services from here..., so what exactly are these Permissions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GKE cluster will be created with the permissions that is set on the 'Access scopes' section in the 'Advanced edit' tab. So only the APIs with the access enabled in this section will be shown as enabled.
These permissions denote the type and level of API access granted to the VM in the node pool. Scopes inform the access level your cluster nodes will have to specific GCP services as a whole. Please see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam) for more information about accesss scopes.

In the tab of 'Create a Kubernetes cluster', click 'Advanced edit'. Then you will see another tab called 'Edit node pool' pops up with more options.  If you click 'Set access for each API', you will see the option to set these permissions.

'Permissions' are defined when the cluster is created. You can not edit it directly on the cluster after the creation.  You may want to create a new cluster with  appropriate permissions or create a new Node Pool with the new scopes you need and then delete your old 'default' Node Pool as specified in  this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134385/is-it-necessary-to-recreate-a-google-container-engine-cluster-to-modify-api-perm) .

Comment: When I would enable permissions of my cluster for Cloud SQL would this 'replace' the 'Service Account with a secret' approach, or how does this 'work together'?