# socket.io turns without any results

Tags: laravel, socket.io

I installed a new Laravel application after the description https://medium.com/@dennissmink/laravel-echo-server-how-to-24d5778ece8b

I did after i tried to install socket.io in an current application. In both cases there is the problem that the socket.io turns without any results.

vagrant@homestead:~/code/test$ laravel-echo-server start

L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.5.0

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!

Channel: test-event
Event: App\Events\ExampleEvent
Channel: test-event
Event: App\Events\ExampleEvent

```
            window.Echo.channel('test-event')
                .listen('ExampleEvent', (e) => {
                    alert(e)
                    console.log(e);
                });
```

What is missing that the socket.io does not get any results? Any hint?

Comment: i think you forgot to make the ExampleEvent implements ShouldBroadcast interface in the server

Comment: Should Broadcast is implemented

Comment: I tested with another github project. there is the following error: `app.js:38876 WebSocket connection to 'wss://test.local:6001/app/websocketkey?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381444/websocket-connection-failed-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-respon check this