# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400 in socket.io-redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, redis, socket.io

**In my current project I use socket.io-redis to scale my socket.io servers. However, when trying to connect to the reds server, I get the following error :**

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

**My client side code :**

```
const socket = io(<url to redis server>, {transports: ['websocket']})
```

**My server side code:**

```
const redis = require('socket.io-redis');

io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

Comment: follow these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381444/websocket-connection-failed-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-respon/41383819#41383819

Comment: @SaeidAlidadi The error is still there. Is it because I am using the redis url ?

Comment: You should connect your socket client  to your server. the `.io.redis` is just an adapter for multiple instances of one `nodejs` server for sharing socket sessions between them.

Comment: @SaeidAlidadi So I have to connect it to my biggest server and not to redis

Comment: @SaeidAlidadi I thought that redis manages incoming connections and splits it up between servers

Comment: You should just connect all of your servers that have the same logic to one redis with the adapter and then connect socket clients to these servers. the connection has a round robin behavior so one client will connected to one server and this will retried if your connection get lost