# WebSocket connection to "wss://mydomain.com/one/of/app/graphql" failed - NestJS GraphQL, docker, nginx

Tags: nginx, websocket, nestjs, apollo-client, apollo-server

Have problem with secured websocket connection. I have app running on https, where mutations and queries works, but cannot establish wss connection :/ When I run the react app on not secured connection (http) and use ws then all is ok. I am not sure what may cause this issue - maybe nginx proxy, maybe nestjs graphql config or maybe react apollo client. Shortly:

Have server with nginx with configured cert. The server proxy subdirectory of my domain to some app (runned in docker container and exposed on port 3000):

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name mydomain.com
  [...cert configs...]

  location /one/of/app/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/
  }
}
```

As I mentioned the website works with secured connection, but the wss connection failed. I do not do anything extra in server or client - all configuration all the same instead the uri (https, wss instead http, ws). On not secured connection, with ws:// websocket works. Any sugestions?

Full error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.com/one/of/app/graphql' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48096141/13514288

Added for api (/one/of/app/) nginx proxy extra headers:

```
location /one/of/app/ {
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/
}
```